# Trying to run some 3D game but its giving this error even though mine are the latest drivers..whats wrong?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card

“Unable to run because your video card drivers did not install properly, are out of date, or are for unsupported hardware. Please make sure you have the latest video card drivers and even if you do have the latest, try reinstalling them.”

I d/l some utility s/w "PC Pitstop Driver Alert2" that had no updates for my driver..it says the video card driver is already up to date...
The driver name listed in Display Adapters is this:-

Intel(R) 82945G Express Chipset Family (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM 1.0)

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate Operating System

Why am I not able to run the game!?? Help!

Comment: Problems with computer games are off topic for SuperUser. Try our sister site instead: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: oh ok..didnt know abt this site..wow how many are there ? I come to know about yet another stackexchange site every day..lol

Comment: @Nifle IMO the fact this is about a game is almost irrelevant *in this case* - replace "3D Game" in the above with "3D modelling software", and I this would be perfectly acceptable. The question isn't *about* the game (which would be OT). Anyway **@user48697**, simply put I suspect the problem is the bit of the error that states `or are for unsupported hardware` because frankly the Intel 82945G is not really gaming capable and any game that requires a posh bit of functionality (shaders and all the other magic modern gfx cards can do) will not work.

Comment: @DMA57361 - I was almost sure it was game related per `or are for unsupported hardware` Over on Gaming he might get som suggestions to get around that

Comment: @DMA :: I actually have installed Windows 7 recently..been having this problem since then..I had Windows XP Pro earlier..then the game would work alright without any problems

Comment: I concur that it's probably game-specific and probably actually a fairly generic error message. I'd look into that.

Comment: I d/l the setup file of the game again..still the same error

Comment: @Nifle hmmm true, and given the additional information provided I see the point. However, where is the line drawn between "games go on gaming" and the generic troubleshooting done on SU for every other type of software? (also do gaming.SE *want* troubleshooting Q's; are they on-topic over there?)

Comment: @DMA57361 - Good question, I'll head over there and ask. http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1173/is-questions-about-games-that-wont-start-wanted-here

Comment: @DMA57361 - Seems questions like that are welcome http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1173/is-questions-about-games-that-wont-start-wanted-here/1174#1174

Comment: @Nifle - well they were quick. Was still finishing up my comment saying that was a good idea to just ask them directly, etc. Anyway, given gaming.SE are willing to deal with them, I'm happy to support closing (eventually migrating?) these types of questions. They are, as you point out, likely to be more capable of answering over there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

945 is [not supported](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-025526.htm) under Windows 7, so the program cannot make full use of your IGP.

> Intel(R) 82945G Express Chipset Family **(Microsoft Corporation - WDDM 1.0)**

Indicates that the drivers were provided by Microsoft, rather than Intel and the drivers installed maynot be upto the mark

Comment: so what do I do now ? What graphic driver do I need to install ? How do i find it ?

Comment: @user Try running the software in a few compatibility modes to see what happens (right-click the `exe` and look at the compatibility tab). It may also be worth trying to install the Vista drivers from Intel, as they *might* work in place of real Win7 ones.

Comment: @DMA - Compatibility mode is unlikely to work. @user48697 - Might be worthwhile to try out the Vista drivers, but might cause boat loads of BSOD's.